# Laravel 5.7 customize resend mail method

Tags: laravel

I customized my LoginController to prevent a user from logging in if the account is not validated since this is not the default Laravel behavior.

Now that a user is logging and the account is not validated, I ask him if he wants to have a new mail notification to validate his account. Since I have no `$request->user()` I don't know on how I can override this method :

VerificationController.php

```php
public function resend(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->user()->hasVerifiedEmail()) {
        return redirect($this->redirectPath());
    }

    $request->user()->sendEmailVerificationNotification();

    return back()->with('resent', true);
}
```

I thought about getting the mail of the user but how can I send him an email based on his mail and not on `user()` as Laravel expects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of options, the easiest of which would be to make use of [Signed URLs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/urls#signed-urls) to allow `resend` to accept a user `id` parameter, then when a user logs in and isn't verified you redirect them to the `resend` page with their `id` to identify their account without an active user session.

For example, your login controller would look something like this:

```php
if (! $user->hasVerifiedEmail()()) {
    return redirect()->to(URL::signedRoute('resend', ['id' => $user->id]));
}
```

And your `VerificationController@resend` method would look something like this:

```php
public function resend(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->input('id') && $request->hasValidSignature()) {
        $user = User::findOrFail($request->input('id'));
    }

    $user = $user ?: $request->user();

    if ($user->hasVerifiedEmail()) {
        return redirect($this->redirectPath());
    }

    $user->sendEmailVerificationNotification();

    return back()->with('resent', true);
}
```

That said, Laravel includes middleware for requiring email verification: it does allow login, but it won't allow the user to do anything until they verify so unless you have a reason to prevent login completely, the middleware meets your needs. You can find information on the middleware [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/verification#protecting-routes).